# npm run build is failing on CI but runs fine on local machine

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cicd

I got this weird problem. I use vitejs for my app, the build is work fine on my local machine, but cannot build my app using npm run build on Github Actions.
here is my CI/CD workflow:

```
name: CI

on: push
jobs:
  lint-format:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [16.x]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Commit
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - name: Install deps
        run: |
          npm ci
      - name: Run lint
        run: |
          npm run lint
      - name: Run prettier
        run: |
          npm run format
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [16.x]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Commit
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - name: Install deps
        run: |
          npm ci
      - name: Run test
        run: |
          npm run test
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [16.x]
    needs: [lint-format, test]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Commit
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - name: remove node_modules
        run: rm -rf node_modules/
      - name: Install deps
        run: |
          npm ci
      - name: Run build
        run: |
          npm run build
```

and my typescript config tsconfig :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["src","src/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts",".eslintrc.cjs", "vitest.config.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

The jobs passed, and got this error on build job, anyone can what happened or what missing my workflow?
[image]

Comment: When you say build is working fine for you locally does that mean running `tsc` doesn't output any errors locally? Or are you only testing `vite build` locally? Also, are you using any vite plugins like components/auto imports? If that's the case have you pushed the generated .d.ts files to your repo?

Comment: @brc-dd I use only `vite build` locally, actually  this is my first react/typescript project, what the knowledges I miss for typescript/react build? is `vite-build` not enough to do everything for me?

Comment: In your CI, you are running `tsc && vite build`, but locally you are only using `vite build`, that's why it's working locally for you. Running `tsc` locally will also give those errors. You need to change `npm run build` in your CI workflow to `npx vite build` if you don't want `tsc` to run. `vite build` is sufficient in a sense, but it won't catch up ts errors (the ones you're getting), you need `tsc` for that.